# Return the first and last name of customers whose email is not in the format of "<first_name>. <last_name>@email.org"

Tags: sql, postgresql

Hello I am new to sql and I have these question:

Return the first and last name of customers whose email is not in the format of "<first_name>.<last_name>@email.org".

and here is my code.

```
SELECT first_name, last_name
FROM customer
WHERE email LIKE '%<first_name>.%<last_name>%@email.org';
```

It returns me with 0 rows and columns where in fact all emails are in the correct format.
It seems I am wrong in my 'LIKE' statement.

Answer (score 1):

**Schema (PostgreSQL v13)**

```
CREATE TABLE customer (
  "first_name" VARCHAR(6),
  "last_name" VARCHAR(5),
  "email" VARCHAR(19)
);

INSERT INTO customer
  ("first_name", "last_name", "email")
VALUES
  ('bob', 'joe', 'bob.joe@gmail.com'),
  ('tom', 'larry', 'tom.larry@gmail.com'),
  ('little', 'foot', 'lilfeet@hotmail.com');
```

---

**Query**

```
SELECT first_name, last_name
FROM customer
WHERE email LIKE first_name || '.' || last_name || '%';
```

| first_name | last_name |
| --- | --- |
| bob | joe |
| tom | larry |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/wqUo7DbnmJXALUFvwMDyaW/1)

Comment: John is mentioning NOT in format. You have to negate your like :)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try below? Also, adding a data sample would be helpful.

```
SELECT first_name, last_name
FROM customer
WHERE email NOT LIKE '%'||first_name||'.%'||last_name||'%@%.%';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a regular expression:

```
-- Any lines where email = first_name.last_name@
        
  SELECT first_name, last_name FROM customer WHERE email ~ format('[%s]+[.]+[%s]+@',first_name,last_name)
    

-- Any lines where email = *.*@
    
 SELECT first_name, last_name FROM customer WHERE email ~ '[\w]+[.]+[\w]+@'
```

Result:

| first_name | last_name |
| --- | --- |
| bob | joe |
| tom | larry |

Demo in [DBfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=1eeb37e6afa215c64f510caaf2cd4554)